# Can I install Android on WinCE platforms?

Tags: android, windows-ce

I had few pieces of hardware which run on WinCE 5 and 6. I wanted to know if there was any program I could use to install Android on it without having to write drivers etc for it.

I am looking for a solution similar to XDAndroid project but for WinCE systems.

Thanks! Please let me know what options I would have on this.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no general solution. Each device will need its own hardware drivers written for Android. XDAndroid works because HTC is reusing a lot of their same hardware, so the same build of Android, with limited modifications, mostly works on each of their new devices. While the HaRETS bootloader could work for CE5/6, Android itself almost certainly won't boot without significant changes to the OS' drivers. It's not impossible, but it would take quite a lot of work.